# Assign value from another object within same object

Tags: javascript, json

How can I get the value of another object from the same JSON while declaring?

```
var constant = {

    roles: {
      ADMIN: 'admin',
      CONSUMER: 'consumer',
      SUPER_ADMIN: "super_admin"
    },

    webAccess : [roles.ADMIN]

}

console.log(constant);
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
  "roles": {
    "ADMIN": "admin",
    "CONSUMER": "consumer",
    "SUPER_ADMIN": "super_admin"
  },
  "webAccess": [
    "admin"
  ]
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? please explain further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as following:

```js
var constant = {

    roles: {
      ADMIN: 'admin',
      CONSUMER: 'consumer',
      SUPER_ADMIN: "super_admin"
    },

    get webAccess() {
        return [this.roles.ADMIN];
    } 

}

console.log(constant);
```

Comment: I don't want to declare it with the different value. Please check my question. Your answer is obvious I can.

Comment: @HardikShah - Please check now as I've edited my response.